# Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, intellij-idea

```
if (Math.random() <= .1) {
                    let orgAdmin = User.find({email: 'test1@example.com'});
                    org.administrators.push(orgAdmin._id);
                }
```

what do I get this error and how to fix it? ideas? thanks

Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: What is `org` here?

Comment: @adiga it is another file organization

Answer (score -1):

try adding `console.log(org)` before calling `org.administrators.push()`. That message is telling you the property `administrators` is undefined on org.

you could also add a check to see if the property is defined before trying to interact with it, and if it's not then create the array. e.x.

```
if (Math.random() <= .1) {
    let orgAdmin = User.find({email: 'test1@example.com'});
    if(org.administrators) {
        org.administrators.push(orgAdmin._id);
    } else {
        org.administrators = [orgAdmin._id];
    }
}
```